# Solution for url redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have some issue with redirecting urls. I have a url www.roundandpay.nl and i want to redirect it to www.jeroenvanewijk.nl/roundnpay. When I set a "normal" redirect then the site will be loaded in a frame that isnt responsive. So on a mobile divce i get an desktop version.

I have looked in to a dns redirect but that wont work ceaus i cant reffer to a subfolder on my server.

The other solution i did look in to was a index.php with a redirect header. But I cant get it working.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: _Can't get it working_ where is code?

Answer (score 2):

just add the following meta tag to your `<head>` element

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0.1;URL=yourURL">
```

in the `<head>` tag of www.roundandpay.com `index.php` file add

```
 <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0.1;URL=http://www.jeroenvanewijk.nl/roundnpay">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just prefer the URL Redirection Plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ which will redirect you in a better way. ***You never need to hard code any URL into the Website Code.***

If you use this plugin you will never have any type of redirection issue for both the Desktop and as well as the mobile. It is the best for all type of redirection that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thnx for the quick respon!
There is only one problem to the solution. I have only bought the domain www.roundandpay.nl and not a hosting so I can upload files to it. I can only upload files to www.jeroenvanewijk.nl/roundnpay